# MongoDB stores "Promise" object instead of hashed password

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, bcrypt

I am using bcrypt to hash passwords and MongoDB as my database.

Here is the code:

```
export default function buildMakeUser({pwdHasher})
{
    return function makeUser({
        username,
        email,
        password,
        password_hash = pwdHasher(password), // the important part
        favoriteColor
    } = {})
    {

// ...
        return Object.freeze({
            getUsername: () => username,
            getEmail: () => email,
            getHashedPassword: () => password_hash,
            getFavoriteColor: () => favoriteColor
        });
}
```

And here is `pwdHasher`'s definition:

```
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import buildMakeUser from "./entity/user.js";

async function pwdHasher(password){
    let hashed;
    hashed = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    return hashed;
}
```

However, when I store the user in the database, here's the result:

```
  ops: [
    {
      username: 'kibe',
      email: 'blabla@gmail.com',
      password_hash: [Promise],
      _id: 5ecc8b752e0aa53e87d5b62a
    }
  ],
```

It seems like `makeUser`'s object does not wait for `pwdHasher(password)`. I have tried wrapping `pwdHasher` in a Promise and it also did not work.

Does anyone know why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions I see based on your code snippet:

**First way:**(Recommended)
Use `await` when calling the `async` function. The code will be:

```
export default function buildMakeUser({pwdHasher})
{
    return function makeUser({
        ...
        password_hash = await pwdHasher(password), // the important part 
        ...
    })  
}
```

**Alternative way:**
Use [`hashSync`](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#api) method of `bcrypt` instead of using async-await.

Comment: the `hashSync` method worked. but... why? shouldn't `password_hash` call `pwdHasher` which then awaits for `hashed`? thank you by the way!

Comment: bcrypt hash API works asynchronously. It returns a promise and you get the return value when the promise is fulfilled.  The hashSync API makes this synchronous, i.e. the execution waits until it returns the value.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `pwdHasher` as:

```
async function pwdHasher(password) { ... }
```

But you call it as:

```
password_hash = pwdHasher(password),
```

By definition, an async function RETURNS A PROMISE. If you'd like to get the value from the promise, you must either `await` the result or use `pwdHasher(password).then(...)`